# Summary Within tool not matching Select by Location results

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location

[image: Screenshot]

This seems like it should be simple but having trouble. Using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.

What I would like to do: count the number of polygons from one layer intersecting polygons in another. In this case, I'm counting the number of fires that have occurred in each county of the state. I would ultimately like to export a table the counts number of fires in five-year increments by county.

What I have done: I added a COUNT field in the fire layer, and used the Field Calculator to apply a value of one. Then I use the Summarize Within tool, grouped by each unique fire, to sum the values of the COUNT field. This 'works,' in that the operation is performed and I get a nice-sounding value, but the number is consistently off. When I have done a 'select by location' for fires that intersect a given county, the selected number is consistently higher than than the count yielded by the Summarize Within tool. If I do the Select by Location tool and change the relationship to 'Within' that number is also consistently higher.

Would like help on why this may be OR other suggestions for counting polygons based by their intersection of other polygons in another layer.